# Sorting is not working on Custom DataType (Currency Class) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, oop

Hi Folks i have one field Price and it has Custom datatype i.e. Class that represents a currency which has properties i.e. CurrencySymbol, CurrencyCode and CurrencyValue. And i want to apply sorting on Price by its value. Can someone please help me on that.

```
public class Currency 
    {
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
var rows = dataTable.Select(filters, "Price Asc");
```

I have read many articles but not getting exact solution.

Comment: Please share the `dataTable`, `filters` by providing the data. Thanks.

Comment: Without an exchange table, it doesn't make much sense to sort by value, disregarding currency. But if you want or need to anyway: implement the [comparable interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-8.0). Or create an external comparer class (derived from [Comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=net-8.0)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is 2 approach for that
First (quick) :
sort your enumerable using linq and lambda

lets assume you have an Enumerable (Like List and Array) of Currency type named currencies

you can sort it using Linq and lambda as blow example :

```
//for ascending order and store the rows in a List
var orderedCurrencies = currencies.OrderBy(p=>p.Value).ToList();

//for descending order and store the rows in a List
var orderedCurrencies = currencies.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Value).ToList();
```

for more investigation you should refer to [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) documentation

The Second Approach is more OOP friendly and i suggest to use this when you want to respect object oriented software architecture

Fist Implement IComparable interface for your Currency Object So that the Object Can be Compared like the Example blow :

```
public class Currency : IComparable<Currency>
{
    [...]

    public int CompareTo(Currency that)
    {
        return this.Value.CompareTo(that.Balance);
    }
}
```

and sort it with Linq as the example blow :

```
//for ascending order and store the rows in a List
var orderedCurrencies = currencies.Order().ToList();

//for descending order and store the rows in a List
var orderedCurrencies = currencies.OrderDescending().ToList();
```

for more investigation you should read [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable) documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ` to sort the rows based on the `Currency` property. Assuming your `DataTable` has a column named `Price` with a custom data type `Currency`.

```
var sortedRows = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(row => ((Currency)row["Price"]).Value)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

[See this **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8BTGAC).